# How to show the multiple results in Datatable with two columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, bootstrap-4

In the below code, it will return only the Date.How to show this on HTml table with two columns??
I need to create the Frequency column based on the result.. every first row of frequency column is 1st basic treatment..

I want to show in an Html table with two columns like 
**Expected Output**

```
**Date**         **Frequency**
19-Jan-2019     1st Basic treatment
05-Feb-2019     2nd Control Treatment
----------
----------
17-Dec-2019     12th Control treatment
```

```js
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
return date; }


function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "June", "July",
    "Aug", "Sept", "Oct",
    "Nov", "Dec"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return day + '-' + monthNames[monthIndex] + '-' + year;
}


function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
var numWorkDays = 0;
var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
        numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
        numWorkDays = 0;
        //console.log(currentDate);
        console.log(formatDate(currentDate));
    }
} }
var start = new Date("2019-01-01");
var end = new Date("2019-12-31");
var period = 15;
printNextPeriod(start, end, period);
```

Comment: Have a look at the different getter methods for your date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date - you'll find getFullYear(), getDate() and getMonth() which you can use to output your date as you want.

Comment: `'Sat Jan 19 2019 04:00:00 GMT+0400'.replace(/^.{4}|GMT/g,'')` does the job for me. ;-)

Comment: From dupe: `function dateToYMD(date) {
    var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = strArray[date.getMonth()];
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y;
}`

Comment: @mplungjan How to show this an Html table??like two columns?

Comment: @mplungjan on every 1st treatment i need to show like 1st Basic treatment and others 2nd control treatment,3rd control treatment so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you changed your question a solution could be this

Change the divs to table cells if you really want a table

You can use document.createElement and a tbody.appendChild

```js
function nth(d)  { if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';  switch (d % 10) { case 1:  return "st"; case 2:  return "nd"; case 3:  return "rd"; default: return "th"; } }
function dateToYMD(date) { var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; var d = date.getDate(); var m = strArray[date.getMonth()]; var y = date.getFullYear(); return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y; }
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) { var date = new Date(this.valueOf()); date.setDate(date.getDate() + days); return date; }
function pad(str) { return (" "+str).slice(-2) }
var cnt = 0, dataSet = [];

function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
  var numWorkDays = 0;
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
      numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
      numWorkDays = 0;
      cnt++; 
      let treatment = pad(cnt) + nth(cnt) + (cnt == 1 ? " Basic" : " Control") + " Treatment"
      dataSet.push([dateToYMD(currentDate),treatment]);
    }
  }
}

var start = new Date("2019-01-01");
var end = new Date("2019-12-31");
var period = 15;
printNextPeriod(start, end, period);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{ title: "Date" },
              { title: "Frequency" }
    ],
    order: [ [1, "asc"] ],
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
  </div>
```

Comment: Anything is possible.

Comment: My contact details are in my profile. I am not expensive;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590000/how-to-skip-holidays-from-the-set-of-result

Comment: I made a datatable for you.

Comment: Someone else will answer - I do not do php