# How to skip Holidays from the set of result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

Is it possible to skip Holidays also?? Assume i have set of holiday list in database..holidays will not comes to the result date.I want to skip the holiday date and skip to next date is fine

if holiday is 05-Feb-2019 then skip this date and need to show 06-Feb-2019(exclude Fridays)..Then next 30 days will be 13-Mar-2019 (30days calculating from 06 Feb)

for example

```
var holidays = array("05-Feb-2019", "08-Oct-2019", "17-Dec-2019"); 

function nth(d) {
  if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th'; 
  switch (d % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";
  }
}

function dateToYMD(date) { var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; var d = date.getDate(); var m = strArray[date.getMonth()]; var y = date.getFullYear(); return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y; }

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

var cnt = 0;
function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
  var numWorkDays = 0;
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
      numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
      numWorkDays = 0;
      cnt++; 
      document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += dateToYMD(currentDate)+"<br/>";
      document.getElementById("second").innerHTML += cnt+nth(cnt)+(cnt==1?" Basic":" Control")+ " Treatment"+"<br/>";

    }
  }
}

var start = new Date("2019-01-01");
var end = new Date("2019-12-31");
var period = 30;
printNextPeriod(start, end, period);
```

Now the code results like

```
**Date**
05-Feb-2019   
12-Mar-2019
-----------
12-Nov-2019
17-Dec-2019
```

Expecting output with skiping holidays

```
06-Feb-2019(exclude fridays)
13-Mar-2019
----------
so on
```

```js
function nth(d) {
  if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';
  switch (d % 10) {
    case 1:
      return "st";
    case 2:
      return "nd";
    case 3:
      return "rd";
    default:
      return "th";
  }
}

function dateToYMD(date) {
  var strArray = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = strArray[date.getMonth()];
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

var cnt = 0;

function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
  var numWorkDays = 0;
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
      numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
      numWorkDays = 0;
      cnt++;
      document.getElementById("first").innerHTML += dateToYMD(currentDate) + "<br/>";
      document.getElementById("second").innerHTML += cnt + nth(cnt) + (cnt == 1 ? " Basic" : " Control") + " Treatment" + "<br/>";

    }
  }
}

var start = new Date("2019-01-01");
var end = new Date("2020-01-01");
var period = 30;
printNextPeriod(start, end, period);
```

```css
.period {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="period" id="first">**Date**
  <hr/>
</div>
<div class="period" id="second">**Frequency**
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: Can any one help me to do this?and results show in a Datatableof jquery

Comment: can u make a fiddle for this?

Comment: @NIshamMahsin http://jsfiddle.net/2mjshr1d/

Comment: @NIshamMahsin plz try to make this in an datatable..becoz if more than 3 year contract means it will show continuoulsy..if using datatable, then pagination will appear

Comment: by holidays do u mean saturday ,sunday?

Comment: @NIshamMahsin public holidays

Comment: where is that list?

Comment: @NIshamMahsin Already am skipping weekends (Fridays) in that code...

Comment: @NIshamMahsin give some example list in an array.I will fetch this from database like an array var holidays = array("05-Feb-2019", "08-Oct-2019", "17-Dec-2019");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
function nth(d)  { if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';  switch (d % 10) { case 1:  return "st"; case 2:  return "nd"; case 3:  return "rd"; default: return "th"; } }
function dateToYMD(date) { var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; var d = date.getDate(); var m = strArray[date.getMonth()]; var y = date.getFullYear(); return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y; }
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) { var date = new Date(this.valueOf()); date.setDate(date.getDate() + days); return date; }
function pad(str) { return (" "+str).slice(-2) }
var cnt = 0, dataSet = [];

function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays) {
  var numWorkDays = 0;
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
      numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
      numWorkDays = 0;
      cnt++;
      let date = dateToYMD(currentDate);
      let pos = holidays.indexOf(date);
      if (pos != -1) {
        console.log("replace",date,"with",instead[pos])
        date = instead[pos];
      }  
      let treatment = pad(cnt) + nth(cnt) + (cnt == 1 ? " Basic" : " Control") + " Treatment"
      dataSet.push([date, treatment])
    }
  }
}

var holidays = ["2019-02-07" // Thursday
  , "2019-10-08", "2019-12-17",
  "2019-02-05" // Friday
];
var instead = [];
holidays.forEach((hol,i) => {
  let d = new Date(hol);
  let date = d.getDate() + 1
  d.setDate(date); // next day (could be Weekend);
  while (d.getDay() === 5) {
    date = d.getDate()
    date++;
    d.setDate(date); // is any day not friday ok?
  }
  instead.push(dateToYMD(d))
  holidays[i] = dateToYMD(new Date(hol))
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(instead))
var start = new Date("2018-12-15");
var end = new Date("2019-12-31");
var period = 15;
printNextPeriod(start, end, period);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{ title: "Date" },
              {title: "Frequency"}],
    order: [[1, "asc"]]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
  </div>
```

Comment: 17-Dec-2019 is a holiday know but in result its showing

Comment: It shouldn't. Let me look. The code should normally work

Comment: ya definitly..but when i run the code..See the last date 20th control treatment?17th dec 2019 mentioned in holidays array know..but wrongly showing

Comment: Ahh, Holidays are yyyy-mm-dd and date is yyyy mmm dd

Comment: can u plz make holday list also yyyy mmm dd

Comment: in database , 2019-12-19 format only..Is it possible to change 19-Dec-2019 all dates like  these to arrays???

Comment: I fixed my code. What do you mean by format? Is the format I use not ok?

Comment: am facing some issues ["05-Mar-2019","02-Jun-2019","03-Aug-2019"]
(index):69 replace 31-Jan-2019 with 05-Mar-2019 in this 31 jan 2019 replace with  02-feb 2019 right?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Thu 31st of Jan should become Mon 4th of Feb - and it does not?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I will check

Comment: Please create a period and a holiday list that shows what you mean. I tried but failed

Comment: in this example feb is missing Thats y am thinking y its not showing Feb

Comment: Fixed it I believe `while (d.getDay() === 5) {
    date = d.getDate();
    date++;
    d.setDate(date); 
  }
` http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/v3ex2Lrk/

Comment: thank u so much sir..You have a great helping mentality..Thanks for the help sir.Such a great Man :)

Comment: helo sir do u know how to pass these results(function results) using ajax???i need to insert to database.so through ajax  i need to pass these arrays.I need to add date and frequency to database table

Comment: How to start with the date 2018-12-15 instead of results starting with 01-Jan-2019.I need to show the results with the date 15-Dec-2018, 01-Jan-2019 etc...

Comment: @numukisdf - I am confused. You need to show where? The screen shows the format you want I convert all dates to DD-MMM-YYYY before showing

Comment: no sir..dont change the format...In your code its starting 01 jan 2019 but i need to start the date with whatever we are giving as start date

Comment: It start with the first work day depending on whatever you give as a start date. Try `var start = new Date("2018-10-15");`

Comment: already in our code having ... var currentDate = new Date(startDate); right??so it is taking after 15days means it will displaying next date..but i need to display startdate..but now it is not displaying start date..Plz check the above snippet..

Comment: Ill look tomorrow